# Warning: This declaration shadows & Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SupplyChain {

```
event Added(uint256 index);

struct State{
    string description;
    address person;
}

struct Product{
    address creator;
    string productName;
    uint256 productId;
    string date;
    uint256 totalStates;
    mapping (uint256 => State) positions;
}

mapping(uint => Product) allProducts;
uint256 items=0;

function concat(string memory _a, string memory _b) public returns (string memory){
    bytes memory bytes_a = bytes(_a);
    bytes memory bytes_b = bytes(_b);
    string memory length_ab = new string(bytes_a.length + bytes_b.length);
    bytes memory bytes_c = bytes(length_ab);
    uint k = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < bytes_a.length; i++) bytes_c[k++] = bytes_a[i];
    for (uint i = 0; i < bytes_b.length; i++) bytes_c[k++] = bytes_b[i];
    return string(bytes_c);
}

function newItem(string memory _text, string memory _date) public returns (bool) {
    Product memory newItem = Product({creator: msg.sender, totalStates: 0,productName: _text, productId: items, date: _date});
    allProducts[items]=newItem;
    items = items+1;
    emit Added(items-1);
    return true;
}

function addState(uint _productId, string memory info) public returns (string memory) {
    require(_productId<=items);
    
    State memory newState = State({person: msg.sender, description: info});
    
    allProducts[_productId].positions[ allProducts[_productId].totalStates ]=newState;
    
    allProducts[_productId].totalStates = allProducts[_productId].totalStates +1;
    return info;
}

function searchProduct(uint _productId) public returns (string memory) {

    require(_productId<=items);
    string memory output="Product Name: ";
    output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].productName);
    output=concat(output, "<br>Manufacture Date: ");
    output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].date);
    
    for (uint256 j=0; j<allProducts[_productId].totalStates; j++){
        output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].positions[j].description);
    }
    return output;
    
}
```

}

Errors I am receiving is:-

1.contracts/test.sol:36:9: Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
Product memory newItem = Product({creator: msg.sender, totalStates: 0,productName: _text, productId: items, date: _date});
^--------------------^
contracts/test.sol:35:5: The shadowed declaration is here:
function newItem(string memory _text, string memory _date) public returns (bool) {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

2. contracts/test.sol:24:5: Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure
   function concat(string memory _a, string memory _b) public returns (string memory){
   ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

Comment: Probably best to use a new version of Solidity (we're on 0.8.19) and not 0.6

Answer (score 1):

Your first error comes from that you have named a variable with the same name as your function:

```
function newItem(...) ... {}
    Product memory newItem = ...
```

Change either the name of the function or the name of the variable in it.

The second error means that you can put `pure` modifier to the funcion, meaning that this funcion does any calculations without the need to read or write data to the blockchain.

You can do it like so:

```
function concat(string memory _a, string memory _b) public pure returns (string memory) {}
```

Good luck.